# Compression of a matrix A by V

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I can't understand and even can't find any text on  Compression of a matrix A by V. meaning if $B=V^*AV$ then B is called the compression of A. What does it mean???

Comment: Please provide some context!

Comment: look for matrix T in the link below   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(operator_theory)

Comment: In general, a [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)) of an operator $A$ is defined as above.

Comment: can you be more specific??? with some example....

Comment: what about the dimensions of $A$ and $V$ and nature of $V$ ...

Comment: I think that you can find something in Bhatia.  I believe that $A$ needs to be square, and $V$ is any matrix such that $V^*V = I$.

Comment: thanks, but the dimension of  $A$ and $V$ will be same???  i have bhatia but nothing is given about....

Comment: No. If $A$ is $n \times n$, $V$ should be $n \times m$.

Comment: thanks Omnomnomnom , but i have to ask you something. i can't put image here as i am new on this forum, can i have your email i.d???

Comment: so if the thing explained above is the compression then see this proof

Comment: so if the thing explained above is the compression then see this proof        http://imgur.com/nRcvTRa                                                                                    matrix $A_v$ is the compression of A in this proof. then,how the eigen vector of $A_v$  and $A$ should have the same length. as they have talked about the intersection of these two subspaces...